# DNS CNAME Record windows 2003 R2 server by IP address

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, cname-record, alias

I am trying to add a CNAME record to point to an ip address. I have added the CNAME record to the primary DNS server that looks like this:

foobar   Alias(CNAME)     192.168.50.11

I restarted the DNS server service. When I ping the new name I get the following:

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

ping foobar

Pinging 192.168.50.11 [67.215.75.132] with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.

Request timed out.

Request timed out.

Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 67.215.75.132:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I have no idea where it is getting the 67.215.75.132 address.

nslookup returns:

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

nslookup foobar

Server:  1server

Address:  192.168.10.10

Name:    192.168.50.11

Address:  67.215.75.132

Aliases:  foobar

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

1server is the machine with the DNS server service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a CNAME to point to the host name defined in the ADDRESS (A) record of the target host instead of the IP.  So whatever hostname 192.168.50.11 is is what goes in the record, not the IP.

foobar Alias(CNAME) targetmachine

Comment: I do not have a A record for the machine. It is not part of the Domain.

Comment: It doesn't have to be part of your domain.  It just has to be resolvable.  In that case, though, you'd put the fully-qualified domain name in the CNAME record.

Comment: I added a A record for the machine with the IP address 192.168.50.11. I then pointed the CNAME to the new host record and that works.

Comment: Good deal :)